# Reverse nibbles of a hexadecimal number in C++

Tags: c++, hex

What would be the fastest way possible to reverse the nibbles (e.g digits) of a hexadecimal number in C++?

Here's an example of what I mean : `0x12345 -> 0x54321`

Here's what I already have:

```
unsigned int rotation (unsigned int hex) {
    unsigned int result = 0;

    while (hex) {
        result = (result << 4) | (hex & 0xF);
        hex >>= 4;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why does it need to be "fast"? What are your requirements and limitations? What is the actual problem this function is supposed to solve?

Comment: The fastest possible way would be a lookup table with a loop over the bytes.

Comment: One slight nuance with your implementation. `rotation(0x00000001)` returns back `0x00000010`.  Is that what you want?  Or do you really want `0x10000000` ?  That has a small implication for the best implementation.

Comment: @selbie `rotation(0x00000001)` returns back `0x00000001`, not `0x00000010`. And I actually want `0x00000001`, or simply `0x1`, the zero's at the beginning don't matter

Comment: Then what you have is probably the best implementation. Look here: https://godbolt.org/z/nbfMfYbs3

Comment: Do you need to sign extend? I was curious why your input param was unsigned int, but your return value was signed int.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be split into two parts:

- Reverse the nibbles of an integer. Reverse the bytes, and swap the nibble within each byte.
- Shift the reversed result right by some amount to adjust for the "variable length". There are `std::countl_zero(x) & -4` (number of leading zeroes, rounded down to a multiple of 4) leading zero bits that are part of the leading zeroes in hexadecimal, shifting right by that amount makes them not participate in the reversal.

For example, using some of the new functions from `<bit>`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <bit>

uint32_t reverse_nibbles(uint32_t x) {
    // reverse bytes
    uint32_t r = std::byteswap(x);
    // swap adjacent nibbles
    r = ((r & 0x0F0F0F0F) << 4) | ((r >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F);
    // adjust for variable-length of input
    int len_of_zero_prefix = std::countl_zero(x) & -4;
    return r >> len_of_zero_prefix;
}
```

That requires C++23 for `std::byteswap` which may be a bit optimistic, you can substitute it with some other byteswap.

Easily adaptable to `uint64_t` too.

Comment: You could just use `__builtin_bswap32()` on gcc/clang.

Comment: Nice! Beat me to it. (And you did a prettier job than I would have — I was looking at bit scan forward / find first set — I didn’t realize the Standard Library has those now. Extra nice!)

Answer (score 1):

i would do it without loops based on the assumption that the input is 32 bits

```
  result = (hex & 0x0000000f) << 28
         | (hex & 0x000000f0) << 20
         | (hex & 0x00000f00) << 12  
  ....
```

dont know if faster, but I find it more readable

Comment: And humans write compilers, for the foreseeable future anyway, so what humans can easily recognize they can easily supply patterns to the compiler to use when optimizing. Sometimes the simplest, most direct code is faster because the compiler has rules that know exactly what to do with it.